# Event waiver needed?

Tags: united-states, liability, waivers

A relative has an event based business (LLC). So far, events for her group have all taken place in restaurants in the city where she resides. Our question relates to liability and need for a waiver, both in the event that a group member gets injured or causes damage. We assumed so far that if a group member gets injured in a business establishment such as a restaurant then it would be the restaurant owner who has potential liability and that if a group member causes damage to a business establishment, it would be the group member's potential liability. But is that the case? In other words, does an event organizer have liability in such cases by virtue of having organized and implemented the event? Would the location of the event matter e.g. a hike through a state park?

Comment: I added "united-states" based upon the state park reference.

Answer (score 2):

> does an event organizer have liability in such cases by virtue of
> having organized and implemented the event?

Potentially yes. Both a liability waiver and an indemnification clause that would require the group member and/or restaurant to pay lawyers to defend you and pay damages incurred if you are sued and lose would be the typical arrangement.